# How many connections (Max.) can be kept in a pool..?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

How does connection pooling works?  i want to know that if i set max. pool size = 20 so are only 20 users able to connect to the web app. at a same time and make a transaction ? What happens to the large websites like Amazon where thousands of users log in at same time throughout the world i.e what pool size do they keep? i am not getting the core concept. I know that a connection pool keeps open connections and users reuse the open connections but i want my first question to be answered.

Comment: I strongly suspect you are going down the wrong path here. Fiddling with the connection pool size won't have the effect you appear to think it will. *Don't change that setting from its default*, or you will experience pain. Lots of pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such document where you can find the maximum size of the pool.Default value of max pool size is `100`

Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: SO if i keep pool size to say 5 so if it is true that only 5 users would be able to connect to and made transaction to a website at  same time...

Comment: I am assuming you are using ADO.NET then a single ADO.NET pool can only go to a single instance, so maximum effective limit is therefore 32767.

Comment: also why it is said that opening a connections to database through web app is costly? Why is it so?

Comment: Think about the amount of memory being allocated per DB Connection. So say if you have 500 DB connection so how much memory will be used and also consider the performance factor!! :)

Comment: **The server maintains several buffers for each client connection. One is used as a communications buffer for exchanging information with the client. Other buffers are maintained per client for reading tables and performing join and sort operations.**

Answer (score 1):

There can be maximum 32767 connections to the database at a time. That is, at a single point of time only 32767 users can make transactions to database via web app. Not even one more than that. A pool size is not mentioned anywhere only default is there(100). But SQL Server will only accept 32767 connections from `user`. Proof: Select @@MAX_CONNECTIONS . If misunderstood please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

The user connections option specifies the maximum number of simultaneous user connections that are allowed on an instance of SQL Server. The actual number of user connections allowed also depends on the version of SQL Server that you are using, and also the limits of your application or applications and hardware. SQL Server allows a maximum of 32,767 user connections. Because user connections is a dynamic (self-configuring) option, SQL Server adjusts the maximum number of user connections automatically as needed, up to the maximum value allowable.